# How can bootstrap plugin disable for desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable Bootstrap jQuery plugin for desktop and reinitialize on mobile, how can i achieve this when testing on Desktop. Is there any way.

I didnt found any pre built solution with plugin, while Foundation provide this functionality with data-interchange.

Comment: Share some code, some fiddle, which plugin ? Give us some element to work with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheLittlePig thanks.... i was using collapse plugin.

i have figure out how to achieve this, using some responsive layout classes, for example i have fixed this as below:

```
 <h3 class="panel-title">
     <span class="hidden-xs">Flight Details</span>
     <a class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-flight-details">Flight Details</a>
 </h3> 

<div id="collapse-flight-details" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">Hi</div>
</div>
```